Why are my skipped and focused tests not raising errors for eslint-plugin-jest?
I have skipped Playwright Node tests but they are not being reported as violations when I run linting with eslint ..
I am using the eslint-plugin-jest package that I've used before in other projects. The rule I use is jest/no-disabled-tests
My tests are using the format test.skip. I don't get an error, just no violations reported.

Playwright doesn't use jest, for starters. Are you using jest-playwright? Why not share an example of your tests and configs? Thanks for clarifying.

The Jest plugin's rules only apply to Jest's globals, by default. You've imported test from @playwright/test, so it knows that's not from Jest. Per the documentation:

You can tell [eslint-plugin-jest] to treat a different package as the source of Jest globals using the globalPackage setting:

In this case:
    settings: {
      jest: {
        globalPackage: "@playwright/test",
      },
    },


As they note, though:

While this can be used to apply rules when using alternative testing libraries and frameworks like bun, vitest and node, there's no guarantee the semantics this plugin assumes will hold outside of Jest

For example, the Jest plugin would not detect the following:
test.describe.skip(/* ... */);

whereas the Playwright plugin would report an "Unexpected use of the .skip() annotation". Also the Playwright plugin lets you allowConditional to support conditional skips, which the Jest plugin would always report on.
Fundamentally it's better to use the plugin actually designed for Playwright.

This can be fixed by switching to the Playwright-specific plugin for ESLint linting.
First (optional) remove the ESLint Jest package:
npm uninstall eslint-plugin-jest

Then install the Playwright-specific package:
npm install eslint-plugin-playwright

Change the import in eslint.config.js from:
import jest from "eslint-plugin-jest";

to:
import playwright from "eslint-plugin-playwright";

and also change:
    plugins: { jest },

to:
    plugins: { playwright },

Then change the usage of any rules to the Playwright plugin format. For example skipped tests are detected with the rule playwright/no-skipped-test instead of jest/no-disabled-tests, i.e. Playwright uses the term "skipped" instead of "disabled" and singular "test" instead of plural "tests".
Note this also requires Node version 18+. With previous versions of Node you'll get errors about invalid ESLint config format.
